# Was Snowboard Kids 2 ever released in Europe?

Tags: snowboard-kids-2

So far as I knew, Snowboard Kids 2 was never officially released in the UK, nor in Europe as a whole. eBay pages sometimes crop up with 'PAL' cartridges from UK sellers, but [in discussions like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/n64/comments/51mads/why_is_snowboard_kids_2_one_of_the_rarest_games/?st=jb3qpus2&sh=0dcd6eed), there are those who say the game's only PAL-territory release was in Australia. The game's [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowboard_Kids_2) lists a European release date but without a citation.

My questions are: was Snowboard Kids 2 officially released in Europe, and if so, was it a very limited release (hence the apparent rarity of the game)? Has it ever been released on another platform besides the Nintendo 64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked at several sources to give you a decent answer. From what I can gather, there has never been a release in Europe. Though some sites do show it being sold in Europe , like you said. The only PAL-release was in Australia.

[[1]](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/0/most-valuable-retro-video-games-in-the-world/snowboard-kids-2/)

> While it's prequel was a standout series on the N64, Snowboard Kids 2
>   was a rarity. It's only non-japanese release was in Australia

[[2]](http://bordersdown.net/threads/78027-snowboard-kids-2)

> If all else fails, the game received a PAL release in Australia I believe

Though [the following site](http://www.vgchartz.com/game/2090/snowboard-kids-2/) mentions that Europe was were 16.% of the sales are from. This is most likely due to ordering out of Australia and being sent to Europe Through Australia. Or perhaps people just buying the Japanese version

**TLDR**: No, it appears there is no european release, those sales are most likely australian version shipped over.

Comment: That certainly explains it's rarity and unofficial European release, if Australian and European N64 games/consoles are compatible.